# Is spring data cassandra thread safe?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

That's the question, is spring data cassandra thread safe? I mean for instance, are the operations exposed by org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository interface thread safe? operations as insert, update, findById, etc... The org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository interface has an implementation class which is org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository, is org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository class thread safe also?

No tries, just a question about spring data cassandra thread safety

Answer (score 0):

the `CassandraTemplate` and `ReactiveCassandraTemplate` are thread-safe and can be reused across multiple instances.

you can check here for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/reference/cassandra/template.html

and `SimpleCassandraRepository` (and its reactive variant `SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository`) use `CassandraOperations` (and `ReactiveCassandraOperations` for the reactive variant) to perform Cassandra operations and the default implementation is `CassandraTemplate` (and `ReactiveCassandraTemplate` for the reactive variant) which will be injected and used by the repositories dynamic proxy.

So `SimpleCassandraRepository` (and its reactive variant `SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository`) are thread-safe in term of performing operations.